# for which value of $a$ that $ \big(\sum\frac {1}{u_n}\big) $ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For any real number $a$ (positive or negative), define a sequence $\{u_n\}$ (depending on $a$) recursively by $u_0=2$ and
$$ \int_{u_n}^{u_{n+1}}(\ln u)^a\,du=1.$$

For which $a\in\mathbb{R}$ does
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{u_n}$$
 converge?

Thank you for your replies

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean? How is $u_n$ defined and where does $a$ appear in the sum? i.e how does the convergence depend on $a$

Comment: @Thorben The $u_i$ are defined inductively by the integral condition.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: just , i see there is only one (un) satisfiying the integral formula , but still hard

Comment: and my interesting the first formula is not far then the density distribution of energy level

Comment: Where'd you come across this problem?  This is very nifty-looking.

Comment: When $a=0$, we have $u_n=n+2$, and so the sum diverges. Notice also that each $u_n$ is a decreasing function of $a$ (slightly nontrivial but true); therefore the sum diverges for $a>0$ as well.

Comment: i derived this problem from normalised constant

Comment: just my dream always to prove RH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that since $\int_2^{+\infty} (\ln u)^a\,du = +\infty$ for all $a$, the sequence $(u_n)$ is well-defined and increasing.

If $a \geq 0$, then $n = \int_2^{u_n} (\ln u)^{a}\,du \geq (u_n-2) (\ln 2)^a$, so $\sum \frac{1}{u_n} = +\infty$.

If $-1 \leq a < 0$, we obtain similarly $(u_n-2)(\ln u_n)^a \leq n \leq (u_n-2) (\ln 2)^a$, which gives $\ln u_n \sim \ln n$ and $u_n = O(n(\ln n)^{-a})$, so we have again $\sum \frac{1}{u_n} = +\infty$.

If $a < -1$, we write
$$
\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{(\ln u_n)^{-a}} \geq \int_{u_n}^{u_{n+1}} \frac{du}{(\ln u)^{-a}} = 1
$$
and we deduce that there exists $c > 0$ such that for all $n$ large enough,
$$
u_n \geq c \sum_{k=1}^n (\ln n)^{-a} \asymp c\, n (\ln n)^{-a}.
$$
Therefore, $\sum \frac{1}{u_n} < \infty$ iff $a < -1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer pleas see:$n-1 = \int_2^{u_n} (\ln u)^{a}\,du$ , for$ n=0$, this formula not verified , pleas give a conditon to you natural number $n$...?

Comment: @rafik: now it's fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Note that an alternate definition of $u_n$ ($n\ge0$) is
$$
\int_2^{u_n} (\ln u)^a\,du = n.
$$
By the same techniques used to asymptotically evaluate the [logarithmic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion), one can show that
$$
\int_2^{y} (\ln u)^a\,du \sim y(\ln y)^a
$$
(with explicit error terms even), from which it follows that
$$
u_n \sim n(\ln n)^{-a}.
$$
Therefore $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/u_n$ diverges if $a\ge-1$ and converges if $a<-1$, by (the limit comparison test and) the integral test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but just the first formula :for $n$=0 the: $\int_2^{u_n} (\ln u)^a\,du = n-2.$ i think it's not verified, look $\int_2^{2} (\ln u)^a\,du = 0-2.$ !!!!!??, i don't understand this